# Compressing PCM data

Tags: c++, c, winapi, voip, voice-recording

I'm using WinAPI - Wave functions to create a recording program that records the microphone for X seconds. I've searched a bit over the net, and found out PCM data is too large, and it'll be a problem to send it through sockets...

How can I compress it to something smaller? Any simple / "cheap" way ?

I've also noticed, when I'm declaring the format using the Wave API functions, I'm using this code :

```
WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
pFormat.wFormatTag= WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // simple, uncompressed format
pFormat.nChannels=1;                    //  1=mono, 2=stereo
pFormat.nSamplesPerSec=sampleRate;      // 44100
pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec=sampleRate*2;   // = nSamplesPerSec * n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
pFormat.nBlockAlign=2;                  // = n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
pFormat.wBitsPerSample=16;              //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
pFormat.cbSize=0;
```

As you can see, `pFormat.wFormatTag= WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;`
maybe I can insert instead of `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` something else, so it'll be compressed right away?
I've checked MSDN for other values, though none of them works for me in my Visual Studio...

So what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: The wFormat tag describes the data.  Changing it will not change the data, it will just cause it to interpret it wrong.  What you need is an encoder which will take PCM and output a compressed format, like ADPCM or Vorbis.

Comment: You need a codec.  What codec do you need?  That depends on your constraints.  Are you recording speech or music or something else?  Are you encoding a file that can be downloaded losslessly or encoding a real-time stream?  If real-time, what's your bandwidth?  Once you've answered these questions you can maybe choose a codec.

Comment: @arx I'm trying to write a small Voice Over IP program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply reduce your sample rate from 44100 to something more manageable like 22050, 16000, 11025, or even 8000.  Most voice codecs don't go higher than 16000 hz anyway.  And the older ones are optimized for 8khz.

The next step is to find a codec.  There's a handful of codecs to use with the [Windows Audio Compression Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but almost all of them date back to Windows 95 and sound terrible by modern standards after being decompressed.

You can always convert to [WMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in real time using the Format SDK or with Media Foundation APIs.  Or just go get an open source MP3 library like [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Since the array is now the length of 24,000, is it still important to compress it ?

Comment: @Amit - That's actually your call. You never mentioned how big your audio data blocks were, performance requirements, or stated goals. So if you are satisfied with the performance, then you are all set. Otherwise, continue to explore more options.

Answer (score 2):

GSM has good compression.  You can convert a block of PCM data to GSM (or any other codec you have installed) using [`acmStreamConvert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Converting Data from One Format to Another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For telephone quality speech you can change to 8 bits per sample and a sample rate of 8000. This will greatly reduce the amount of data.

Comment: Thanks! The array size is now the size of 24,000. Is it small enough to be fast for VOIP? or should I compress it anyway?

Comment: @Amit: The challenge for VOIP isn't your average data rate; it's making sure that you get something reasonable when a packet drops **and** at the same time keeping the latency down.

Comment: @MSalters I can do that with threads, recieving data 24/7, and playing the data through threads.. thats what you meant, no ?

Comment: @Amit: No, not at all. What are you going to do when (not if) you lose a packet? You can't use TCP for VoIP, that introduces stutter. Resending is not an option. You need something called Forward Error Correction.

Comment: @MSalters I see that. you mean, what happend if I send for example the array of the audio sound, and the array is corrupted, or something like that?Thanks! I'll check the subject.

Comment: @Amit: Not corrupted, just plain missing a kilobyte or so in the middle. That's by far the most likely scenario.

Comment: @MSalters I see. So I shouldent be worried much about the size of the socket (I guess an array of 24,000 isnt much with UDP), but the case that the data was lost in the way from one client to another ? (Which is a typical UDP problem)...
Any good ideas to start with the Forward Error Correction? It looks a bit confusing at first sight...

By the way, thanks a lot for your help! :)